# Rails named scopes don't return objects that are in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a User model, which `has_many` Projects.

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

---

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  scope :optionals, -> { where(optional: true) }
  scope :non_optionals, -> { where(optional: false) }
end
```

---

As you can see, a project has a boolean attribute called `optional`.

I build a new project on a user,

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.projects.build(optional: false)
```

I can see that object in memory, with

```
@user.projects  # returns all projects, including the one in memory built above
```

According to the console, the above call to `@user.projects` makes a trip to the database. The following call also makes a trip to the database, but does not include the object in memory:

```
@user.projects.non_optionals  # doesn't return the object built in memory above
```

My question is, how can I allow a named scope to include objects that are in memory?

Answer (score 3):

.build only creates a new object in Ruby space, in fact it's equivalent to using .new with the user property already filled in:

```
# @user.projects.build(optional: false) is equivalent to
Project.new(user: @user, optional: false)
```

Querying the database will naturally not return this record, since it does not exist there. You can use .create to build *and* persist the object into the database:

```
@user.projects.create(optional: false)
@user.projects # will include the object created previously
# you can consider .create as .build.save
```

Comment: Ah, I see. But the call to `@user.projects` queries the database and still returns the object in memory. Why is that?

Comment: When you create the object through the association Rails probably adds it to that association - but this is only in that specific Ruby process. If you start a different console and run @user.projects you will not see the built object.

Comment: I understand that two Ruby interpreter instances won't have access to each others memory. But this is the same Ruby instance. Calling `@object.association` returns in-memory objects, but `@object.association.scope` does not.

Comment: That happens because of two reasons: when you use `.build` the object will be added to the association collection; then, when calling `@object.association` multiple times, the results are cached (ie. the query is not executed multiple times). This means that even if you actually save an object in another console, it won't show up. If you use `@object.association.scope` a query is forced and thus the in-memory object does not show up. You can also bust the association cache (and force a query) using `@object.association(true)`

Comment: Just classic leaky abstraction in ActiveRecord.